# Ошибка при попытке закодировать массив байт, RSA, C#

Tags: c#, криптография, rsa

`RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] ByteForEncode = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(StrForEncode);
byte[] BufferSig = rsa.Encrypt(ByteForEncode, false);`

`rsa.Encrypt(ByteForEncode, false);` - выдаёт эту ошибку:

> `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: "Плохая длина."`
>
> `ByteForEncode = {byte[2558]}, тип :byte[]`

при меньших размерах (ByteForEncode = {byte[128]}) эта ошибка не появляется.
полазил по разным ресурсам интернета, не нашёл конкретных рекомендаций, кроме как "проблема в размере ByteForEncode" и "MSDN откройте, там всё есть"

В итоге: и так понятно, что в размере дело, но как пофиксить я ничего не нашёл, поэтому прошу вас помочь)

Comment: Ключ у вас 1024 бита?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструктор по умолчанию `new RSACryptoServiceProvider()` создает ключ размером 1024 бита. Это значит, что ним можно зашифровать максимум 1024 бита (на самом деле еще меньше, потому что используется криптографическая схема PKCS1, а не прямое шифрование). Если вы хотите зашифровать 2500 байт, вам нужен соответствующей длины ключ. Например:

```
var rsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(16384);
string StrForEncode = new string('x', 2558);
byte[] ByteForEncode = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(StrForEncode);
byte[] BufferSig = rsa.Encrypt(ByteForEncode, false);
```

Генерация такого большого ключа и шифрование занимает очень много времени (можете сами проверить). Вам стоит использовать другую криптографическую схему, никто не шифрует так используя RSA.

Comment: RSA - шифрование, а не кодирование. Шифровать можно данные, которые больше длины ключа, если их разбить на блоки нужной длины.

Comment: В русских терминах не силен, в англ. оно все encryption.

Comment: @Zergatul Благодарю) Коротко, подробно и быстро ответили на вопрос! Редко такое встречается на форумах))

Comment: @Zergatul тащемта нет: encoding не применяется к RSA, а encryption - к base64

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , ахаха, точно, благодарю)

Answer (score 1):

1. Вам нужно разбить исходный массив байтов на блоки длиной 128 байтов
2. Если размер массива не кратен 128 то применить схему [паддинга/выравнивания блоков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F))
3. Далее (если требуется) нужно к блокам применить схему сцепления блоков - [block-chaining](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0) - в тупом варианте оставить как есть (схема ECB).

Не гуру в C# - но подозреваю, что все это имеется в арсенале библиотечных функций.

Comment: Я бы не стал рекомендовать такой подход. 1. Такая схема не используется нигде, а значит не было исследований по поводу ее безопасности. 2. Шифрование RSA очень медленный процесс, для этих целей придумали симметричные шифры.

Comment: Упс, что вы говорите? Это стандартный подход к шифрованию длинных массивов. Если у вас будет массив длиной мегабайт, что будете генерить ключ длиной 8 мегабит? :)

Comment: Это стандартный подход к шифрованию с использованием симметричной криптографии. С асимметричными шифрами (коим является RSA) такой подход не используется.

Comment: Тогда поясните мне как зашифровать мегабайтный массив алгоритмом RSA

Comment: Сгенерировать случайный ключ для симметричного шифра (например 128 бит для AES128), зашифровать его при помощи RSA, а дальше этим ключом шифровать сообщение любой длины при помощи AES и CBC.